# How to uncheck "Close tool dialog" option in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python-script-tool

I have to re-run some of my tools repeatedly. In order to save time I check "Close this dialog" option:

[image]

It is a struggle to uncheck this option for tool that takes a couple of seconds to complete. To stop dialog from closing, I sometimes have to run another tool, that takes longer to complete. In this case I have enough time to uncheck an option while tool is still running.

Are you aware of some better way to do so?

Comment: I also just run a slower tool, although these days I usually just leave it unchecked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this (i.e. in the geoprocessing options) and I'm not at a computer with ArcGIS to check if there is such an option.

I always leave it checked and use the Results tab when I want to check on a tool. That said, one workaround is to write a script tool that runs in the foreground (not background) and does nothing but raise an Exception, that way when you run it the dialog will stay open even if the option is checked (because it didn't complete successfully) and you can then uncheck the option.

Example Python Toolbox (you could do this in a script tool and TBX as well):

```
class UncheckCloseThisDialog(Exception):
    pass

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label =  "Don't \"Close This Dialog\""
        self.alias  = "dont_close_dialog"

        self.tools = [DontCloseThisDialog] 

class DontCloseThisDialog(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Don't \"Close This Dialog\""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        return []

    def execute(self, *args):
        raise UncheckCloseThisDialog('You can now uncheck the "Close this dialog when completed successfully" option')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an intentional error code in the script,
for eg:-arcpy.AddMessage("p"+4).
Since we cant add string and number it will through the error and the dialog box will remain opened at that time uncheck the dialog box.
After that the issue will be resolved